# Include canvas to generated file from axlsx rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html5-canvas, axlsx

Not to be confused with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608058/rails-gem-axlsx-rails-axlsx-adding-image), is there a way to include canvas element into excel file generated by [axls_rails gem](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails)?
I've been digging around axls_rails gem documentation and stackoverflow, still haven't found the way to do it.

The project I'm currently doing now requires me to include a graph (from canvas html) and table into excel file (export)

Thanks in advance!