# Rails 6 Axlsx Excel Gem - Images not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I don't know if it's my fault or if it just doesn't work with Rails 6, but my images in the file are not displaying:

I tried:

```
img = File.expand_path(Rails.root+'app/assets/images/logo.jpg')
```

and also like described in the examples:

```
img = File.expand_path('../logo.jpg', __FILE__)

sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
            image.start_at 5, 20
            image.end_at 7, 22
end
```

The image is found (at least I don't get an error for this) but the only thing I see in the generated file (the rest of the creation works fine) is:

[image]

Could it be the image size not fitting in the cells? Or is it resizing automatically?

Any suggestions or ideas? I don't know what's wrong or what else I could try

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting height and width for the image? Have a look at this old answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47982814/1796645 (potential duplicate question)

If you found a bug, then you could report it in https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/issues

Comment: Hey,
yeah, I tried setting the width and height as well, but unluckily without effect.
I also reported the issue on the caxlsx and the caxlsx_rails GItHub!